# Idiom request for foolishness

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

> Not knowing the root cause and doing something else without solving the actual problem.

Do we have an idiom/single word for the above sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "something else" requires a lot of activity, you can say

> [running around like a headless chicken](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-round-like-a-headless-chicken)

If you are knowingly doing something merely to fend off complaints rather than solve the problem, the activity is a [**sop**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sop)

If the problem doesn't exist in the first place, you can refer to it as

> [tilting at windmills](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-tilting-at-windmills)